# How to append and pair coordinate values in nested for loop

Tags: python, numpy, append, distance

I am finding the distance between two pairs of random points, I am then duplicating the points in a  3 x 3 pattern so that the same points are seen after a certain distance, which is done with a nested for loop. I am trying to find the distance between the newly created points from the a for loop.

I tried using append within the loop to store the points, which gives me the distances, but it is only giving me 24 distances when there should be a lot more between 9 copies of 4 points.

Am I not implementing append correcting to account for additional distances?

Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import math

dist = []

#scale of the plot
scalevalue = 10

x = [random.uniform(1, 10) for n in range(4)]
y = [random.uniform(1, 10) for n in range(4)]

tiles = np.linspace(-scalevalue, scalevalue, 3)
for i in tiles:
    for j in tiles:
        bg_tile = plt.scatter(x + i,y + j, c="black", s=3)
        dist.append(i)
        dist.append(j)
        pairs = list(zip(x + i,y + j))
        
plt.show()

def distance(x, y):
    return math.sqrt((x[0]-x[1])**2 + (y[0]-y[1])**2)

for i in range(len(pairs)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(pairs)):
        dist.append(distance(pairs[i],pairs[j]))

print(dist)
```

Comment: I see `x` and `y` are plain lists and you are doing `x + i` so I'd expect an error there and not at the `dist.append(i)` line, what is the output you are actually seeing?

Comment: I am seeing the distances between the positions of each of the center points of the 3x3 pattern, I assume. I am getting `[-10.0, -10.0, -10.0, 0.0, -10.0, 10.0, 0.0, -10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.5490723814252758, 1.5985711880070652, 3.2443215556507923, 1.6263661505494527, 3.258106715408061, 3.5873679393211675]`, where the last four values are the distances between the four points in the center, and the others are distances of the scale of the plot (scalevalue).

Answer (score 0):

Run your code:

`x` (and `y`) is a list of numbers (4):

```
In [553]: x
Out[553]: [8.699962201099193, 3.1643082386096975, 5.245385542599207, 3.0412506367299033]
```

`tiles` is an array:

```
In [554]: tiles
Out[554]: array([-10.,   0.,  10.])
```

And the first iteration - without the plot, and doing one (i,j) append, rather than the sequential.  This better separates the `i` values from the `j` ones:

```
In [558]: dist=[]
     ...: for i in tiles:
     ...:     for j in tiles:
     ...:         dist.append((i,j))
     ...:         pairs = list(zip(x + i,y + j))

In [559]: dist
Out[559]: 
[(-10.0, -10.0),       # that just reflects how you iterate on tiles
 (-10.0, 0.0),
 (-10.0, 10.0),
 (0.0, -10.0),
 (0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 10.0),
 (10.0, -10.0),
 (10.0, 0.0),
 (10.0, 10.0)]
```

That flat list you show in the comment confuses those values.  Why are you doing this?

`pairs` ends up with the last `i,j` values; earlier iterations are thrown away.

```
In [560]: pairs
Out[560]: 
[(18.699962201099193, 18.63063210113664),
 (13.164308238609697, 12.329695190243902),
 (15.245385542599207, 16.685778921185936),
 (13.041250636729902, 15.89730196643608)]
```

So the first column is:

```
In [561]: i
Out[561]: 10.0
In [562]: x+i
Out[562]: array([18.6999622 , 13.16430824, 15.24538554, 13.04125064])
```

`x` is a list, but `i` is `np.float64`, so the addition is array addition (list 'addition' is `join`).

### pairs

With that last `pairs`:

```
In [567]: alist = []
     ...: for i in range(len(pairs)):
     ...:     for j in range(i+1,len(pairs)):
     ...:         alist.append(distance(pairs[i],pairs[j]))
     ...:         

In [568]: alist
Out[568]: 
[0.8374876734992962,
 1.442060937629651,
 2.8568926932380996,
 1.664725810930718,
 2.9755013255616056,
 3.1987125977481807]
```

What the iteration is doing is get the 6 combinations of these 4 pairs

```
In [574]: distance(pairs[0],pairs[1])
Out[574]: 0.8374876734992962
```

Those 6 values (different in my case because of different random numbers) have nothing to do with the `tile` values that you previously accumulated in `dist`.

If I make a 2d array from `pairs`:

```
In [575]: arr = np.array(pairs); arr
Out[575]: 
array([[18.6999622 , 18.6306321 ],
       [13.16430824, 12.32969519],
       [15.24538554, 16.68577892],
       [13.04125064, 15.89730197]])
```

I can replicate the `distance` with:

```
In [576]: (arr[:,1]-arr[:,0])**2
Out[576]: array([4.80666276e-03, 6.96578941e-01, 2.07473309e+00, 8.15702920e+00])

In [577]: np.sqrt(np.sum(_[:2]))
Out[577]: 0.8374876734992962
```

I don't know what's the significance of this.  `pairs` is just the `x,y` values with an added `10`:

```
In [579]: np.column_stack((x,y))+10
Out[579]: 
array([[18.6999622 , 18.6306321 ],
       [13.16430824, 12.32969519],
       [15.24538554, 16.68577892],
       [13.04125064, 15.89730197]])
```